# how to get the min and max heap size settings of a JVM from within a Java program

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

How to get the min and max heap size settings of a VM from within a Java program?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

max heap size:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Some other calculations which you may find interesting:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
long allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
long totalFreeMemory = freeMemory + (maxMemory - allocatedMemory);
long usedMemory = maxMemory - totalFreeMemory;
```

Comment: I have set my max heap size as 512m.
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() returns 532742144 which is 508.0625

Comment: @sai praveen: yep, and if you set it to 1024m it will return something that approximates 1024m.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use the Runtime object with Runtime.getRuntime() and then use methods like totalMemory() and [freeMemory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory()).

Answer (score 1):

maybe that could help you ?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/perform/JVMTuning.html#wp1109778
http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html
http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp
http://blog.paulgu.com/2008/07/19/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap-size/

Answer (score 1):

```
ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage()
```