# How can I determine the JVM minimum heap size from within a java application?

Tags: java, jvm, runtime, heap-memory

I have reviewed the answer to [how to get the min and max heap size settings of a JVM from within a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253976/how-to-get-the-min-and-max-heap-size-settings-of-a-jvm-from-within-a-java-program) which was helpful, but the accepted answer doesn't appear to answer half of the question. In essence, I want to report the -Xms and -Xmx settings that were used when the JVM was launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the real JVM arguments this should help you. You can get all JVM arguments with the MXBean:

```java
RuntimeMXBean RuntimemxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> arguments = RuntimemxBean.getInputArguments();
```

You have to look for the arguments which start with "-Xm(s|x)". The problem is that the value could be something like "256M".

Comment: Perfect for my needs. We just want to log the JVM settings at start-up to provide some context when reviewing logs associated with problem reports. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

These are the mappings between values you're looking for:

```
-Xmx=Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
-Xms=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The total memory is the same as the `-ms` on startup, but might be higher after it start running.